# Custom OpenVPN iOS client

Tags: ios, openvpn, networkextension

I'm working on a custom iOS OpenVPN client. 
I found this native OpenVPN client core sources https://staging.openvpn.net/openvpn3/

I can build it for the iOS platform.

How can I integrate this OpenVPNClient as an extension to set up an OpenVPN network for iOS devices from my application? Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Alex,
Do you have any example or sample regarding this?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, Do you have any example or sample about your Custom OpenVPN iOS client? Thanks

Comment: Hi I have ovpn file, how can I use it for my iOS vpn app?

Comment: Note that the oepnvpn3 library is under the GPL3/AGPL3 license which makes it impossible to use it in any Apple App Store app

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the Network Extension framework to extend VPN capabilities of an iOS device. The documentation can be found at the link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/Network_Extension_Framework_Reference/

As stated at the beginning of the linked document in order for your app to be able to use the above framework you need a special permission from Apple:

> IMPORTANT
>
> Most Network Extension classes require you to obtain an entitlement from Apple before using them in your code. To request entitlements, visit https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension.

It may or may not be possible to test the framework without such permission in your development devices, however it is unlikely that you can publish the resulting application to the market.

Comment: How do you think is this OpenVPNClient is compatibly with Network Extension framework? I mean API interfaces.

Comment: @AlexBakhitn I can imagine that they area bit different. openvpn was published in 2013, while the NetworkExtension API was first made public in 2016. You might try contacting Gert Doering though who wrote the openvpn client for ios though https://plus.google.com/u/0/102486415329787631392/posts/faSspbtGkcW

Answer (score 2):

You could use [NEPacketTunnelProvider](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nepackettunnelprovider) api in Network Extension Framework.
The packet tunnel provider allow you to create your own vpn tunnel in iOS and the network traffic (raw ip packet) would be routed to your own vpn tunnel. But you may need to handle raw ip packet and integrate with openvpn3.

Comment: Do you have any sample example regarding this ?

Comment: @taha027 did you find ?

Comment: @ShrikantK No but the only way is to use PacketTunnel sample code provided by apple and after customization may b you can achieve it.