# Built-in VPN types in iOS Network Extension

Tags: ios, vpn, ipsec, networkextension

After some research I saw that IPSec is built-in in [iOS Network Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/Network_Extension_Framework_Reference/). Unfortunately, IPSec does not fit our needs.

OpenVPN would be great for our needs but it needs custom implementation of the [OpenVPN source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437555/custom-openvpn-ios-client) - which is something we would like to avoid because of the difficulty of estimate the amount of work and license issues.

That's why I would like to know if there are other built-in VPN protocols than IPSec in iOS Network Extension so that I can check if it could meet our needs.

In Network extension, there is the class [NEVPNProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEVPNProtocolClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NEVPNProtocol). In the description of this class, we can see that the class [NEVPNProtocolIPSec](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NEVPNProtocolIPSecClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NEVPNProtocolIPSec) implements IPSec VPN. But I can't see any other VPN built-in protocol.

Could anyone tel me if he knows of other VPN built-in implementation than IPSec ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

["For NEVPNManager objects, this property can be set to either an NEVPNProtocolIPSec object or an NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 object."](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406378-protocol?language=objc)

For SSL connections, According to the [NetworkExtension API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension):

You can use the NETunnelProvider family of APIs to connect iOS and macOS devices to a VPN server that uses a non-standard network tunneling protocol, such as an SSL-VPN server.

I would also be interested in any further information anyone has about using openVPN in Swift apps.